# Creating a multiarch meta package

Tags: package-management, dpkg, multiarch, metapackages

I'm trying to create a meta-package to install various dependencies (for Android build system), some of the packages should use the i386 version so I tried to use the "Multi-Arch" option but it fails to build.

The package looks like this (removed the other lines here):

```
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: allowed
Depends: libncurses5-dev:i386
```

And when I run `dpkg --build` it says

`'Depends' field, reference to 'libncurses5-dev': invalid architecture name 'i386': a value different from 'any' is currently not allowed"`

Any idea how to proceed?

I'm running this on Ubuntu 12.04 (server).

Comment: You can't depend on a specific architecture of a package. The best you can do is depend on a package that's only available on that architecture (which can then depend on `libncurses5-dev`).

Comment: I am having the same problem. Is anyone found a solution? Do i need  a special version of dpkg to build multi-ach systems?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to have a second package that is `Architecture: i386`-only and `Multi-arch: foreign`:

```
Package: mybuildsystem
Architecture: amd64
Depends: mybuildsystem-i386, <amd64 stuff>

Package: mybuild-system-i386
Architecture: i386
Depends: libncurses5-dev
Multi-Arch: foreign
```

Because[1](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec#Binary_package_control_fields):

> Multi-Arch: foreign
>
> The package is not co-installable with itself, but should be allowed to satisfy the dependencies of a package of a different arch from itself.